# Miss dependency when compile libgui in Android13 sdk

Tags: android, android-source, android-13

when I add header dependency of gralloc header to Android.bp in libgui

- ```
     "libgralloc_metadata_sys_headers",
  ```

cd into frameworks/native/libs/gui and MM
report error：
"module libgui missing dependencies: libgralloc_metadata_sys_headers{os:android,image:vendor.33,arch:arm64_armv8-2a_cortex-a55,sdk:},

I make sure libgralloc compiled correctly and add same dependency into frameworks/av/media/codec2 it works well